# Serialization with cereal: read only first variables

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

I am serializing some data with the cereal lib. I am serializing a number of variables, among `float`, `double`, `std::vector`.

I write it as

```
cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive(ofile);
int _pts_size, _num_cams;
std::vector<point> _points;

(...)

archive(_pts_size, _num_cams, _points);
```

Can I read back `_pts_size` and `_num_cams` ONLY?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you are using a text based archive (XML/JSON) which allows you to use name-value-pairs to do out of order loading (see [this page](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html) and search for "Out of order loading").

What you want to do is not possible using a binary archive, which must serially read in all of the serialized data.